# jQuery performance: $('#selector').live() vs manually bind (when working with ajax requests)

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

When working with content loaded asynchronously is there any difference from a performance point of view between:

```
// .live()
$('#mybutton').live('click', function(e){ doSomething(); });
```

and manually bind() the events we need every time after the content has been loaded:

```
// manual bind every time
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data){
        mycontainer.html(data); // data contains #mybutton
        $('#mybutton').click(function(e){ doSomething(); });  
    }
});
```

?

Comment: http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are different costs, let's look at them:

```
$('#mybutton').live('click', function(e){ doSomething(); });
```

There are 2 main costs here:

- The `#mybutton` selector needs to run immediately for no reason (the result is thrown away, we just wanted the selector anyway...we're binding to `document`).  In this case it's an [`#id` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) so that's a very low cost...in other cases it's not cheap and very wasteful (for example `[attr=something]`).
- Every `click` that bubbles up to `document` now has to be checked against this selector, a per-click evaluation cost, this varies with the number of clicks you expect.

---

Now let's look at the other method:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(e){ doSomething(); });
```

There are 2 main costs here as well:

- The `#mybutton` selector runs, but only once per ajax request.  However, we're not wasting it, we're using the results.
- The `click` handler is bound to an actual element, rather than `document`, so there's a binding cost *each* time it runs, rather than once

However, there's no per-click cost and the selector call itself isn't wasted...so it's better overall, *since you're using an ID*, this isn't true in other cases.

---

In your case, since you're dealing with an ID (and guaranteed a single element), **this is much cheaper**:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(e){ doSomething(); });
```

In other cases, where you're binding hundreds of elements, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is the clear winner, though [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) would be even better.

Comment: According to 'http://api.jquery.com/live/' the live method can work on elements not yet added to the dom. So in his case unless the click handler actually changes he can just set it up once. So there are some gains to be had there. Also, with JQ1.4 he can stop it bubbling up to the top of the tree.

Comment: nice answer. Could you explain what you mean with "rather than document"?

Comment: @nemesis: @Nick means the `document` object, the container for all the elements on the page.  `live` events are bound there so they can catch the events no matter where they occur on the page.

Comment: @Simon - You can't stop it bubbling up, not with `.live()`, that's *how* `.live()` gets the event in the first place...if you stop bubbling (which means *another* bind as well), the `.live()` handler won't work.

Comment: @Nick - I meant bubbling all the way to the top - you can give it context so that it doesn't go to the root. At least that's how I read it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Simon - Right...that's the comment at the bottom of the answer where `.delegate()` is *always* better (it uses `.live()` underneath, with a context...and *still* doesn't run the selector needlessly).

Comment: @Nick ahh not seen that one. Notice its reasonably new so will have to hit the docs again :). Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little, but I wouldn't worry about it. To me the `.live()` method looks much easier to maintain, so I would use that. As long as nothing's going painfully slow there's no need to worry about performance in JavaScript.

Comment: I don't agree. The app I'm building does intensive use of fading, animations, tooltips, galleries and stuff like that so I want to be sure everything will load as smoothly as possible.

If the code is organized in a good way then it won't be difficult to mantain. I'll wrap everything in a function that will be reused for every case.

Comment: Ok, as long as you've carefully considered the value. Many people make a big fuss over optimisation in cases when it's completely unnecessary, and that is what I was advising against.

Comment: Yea I agree with you, in simple cases trying to save 200ms is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your success function, you're attaching an event because that element is now available in your html? Is that so?

If that is the case, then if the function called via the click is always the same then you can use 'live'. Live lets you bind to events that don't yet exist. So you can put this in even before your document.ready. Then as the ajax updates your main document, that event should always work. You won't need to assign it every time.

So you get the performance benefit of not having to do something every time you return from an ajax call, you do the setup without relying on document.ready and its guaranteed to work.

HTH.